# Android setOnClickListener() on HorizontalScrollView Views

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to populate a horizontalscrollview:

```
 for(int I=0; I<jsonArraySize; I++)
        {               
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.best_seller_layout, null);

            TextView txtProductName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_bestSellerName);
            txtProductName.setText(bestSellersList.get(I).getProductName());                
            TextView txtPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_bestSellerPrice);
            txtPrice.setText(String.valueOf(bestSellersList.get(I).getProductUnitPrice()));             
            ImageView imgProductImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_bestSellerImage);
            imgProductImage.setImageBitmap(bestSellersImageList.get(I));                                

            insertPoint.add(findViewById(R.id.dashboard_mylinear));             
            ((ViewGroup) insertPoint.get(I)).addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));               

            final int K = I;                
            insertPoint.get(K).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this,"The index is: " + K, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });             
        }
```

Here, I'm using the setOnClickListener() to Toast the index of each view, but I'm always getting the last index instead of 0,1,2.....etc. There is something fishy with the following line:

```
insertPoint.add(findViewById(R.id.dashboard_mylinear));
```

........ maybe all of layouts seeming the same because of this one, I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was with setting onClickListener to a List Item. Setting listener to the individual Views solved the problem:

```
            final int K = I;
            v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeToast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Pressed Index: "+ K, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not fishy at all. The "K" value is being built once for each "for" iteration and than stops, while the setOnClickListener function is being built and called all over again each time you press the click. So, in order to keep the "K" value still relevant, you will have to get it from inside the onClick function.

Comment: I've modified my code, but still getting the same result :(

Comment: What is the type of "insertPoint"?

Comment: It's a list of Views - List<View> insertPoint = new ArrayList<View>();

Comment: Try to initiate "insertPoint" again inside the "onClick" function.